# Keep ImageView Circular when picture is changed

Tags: android, imageview

I have a circular ImageView inside my profile activity:

[CircularImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxhA6.png)

But if i change the Profile image, i lost the circular frame :(

My Code:

```
 public void setCircularImage(ImageView imageViewCircularProfile){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.profile_pic);
    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
    imageViewCircularProfile.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
}
```

Change Image Method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.action_changePic){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecione"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageViewCircularProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            setCircularImage(imageViewCircularProfile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Any Idea?

Thanks!

Comment: i suggest to use AsyncTask while you loading image .

Comment: Is the initial image also set by `setCircularImage()`? Or is that an image asset?

Comment: The initial image uses the setCircularImage() method to build the circularView. :)

Comment: Malik, i will study about AsyncTask and try soon..